# Evaluate a boolean expression as a string

Tags: c++, strings

Here's my code to evaluate a boolean expression:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

size_t find_in_string(std::string s, size_t begin, size_t end,
                      std::string target) {
  for (auto i = begin; i <= end; i++) {
    bool isAtI = true;
    for (size_t j = 0; j < target.length(); j++) {
      if (i + j > s.length()) {
        isAtI = false;
        break;
      }

      if (s[i + j] != target[j])
        isAtI = false;
    }
    if (isAtI)
      return i;
  }
  return -1;
}

std::string replaceall(std::string input, std::string from, std::string to) {
  std::string answer;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    if (find_in_string(input, i, input.length() - 1, from) == i) {
      answer += to;
      i += from.length() - 1;
      continue;
    }
    answer.push_back(input[i]);
  }
  return answer;
}

size_t get_matching_brace(std::string s, size_t start) {
  if (s[start] != '(')
    return -1;

  long long count = 0;
  for (size_t i = start; i < s.length(); i++) {
    if (s[i] == '(')
      count++;
    if (s[i] == ')')
      count--;
    if (count == 0)
      return i;
  }

  return -1;
}

std::string simplify(std::string expr) {
  expr = replaceall(expr, "true", "1");
  expr = replaceall(expr, "false", "0");
  expr = replaceall(expr, " ", "");

  // remove all parentheses
  while (expr.find('(') != std::string::npos) {
    size_t begin = expr.find('(');
    size_t end = get_matching_brace(expr, begin);

    expr = expr.substr(0, begin) +
           simplify(expr.substr(begin + 1, end - begin - 1)) +
           expr.substr(end + 1, expr.length());
  }

  while (expr.find("!!") != std::string::npos)
    expr = replaceall(expr, "!!", "");
  expr = replaceall(expr, "!0", "1");
  expr = replaceall(expr, "!1", "0");
  expr = replaceall(expr, "1&&1", "1");
  expr = replaceall(expr, "1&&0", "0");
  expr = replaceall(expr, "0&&1", "0");
  expr = replaceall(expr, "0&&0", "0");
  expr = replaceall(expr, "1||1", "1");
  expr = replaceall(expr, "1||0", "1");
  expr = replaceall(expr, "0||1", "1");
  expr = replaceall(expr, "0||0", "0");
  expr = replaceall(expr, "==1", "");
  expr = replaceall(expr, "1==0", "0");
  expr = replaceall(expr, "0==0", "1");
  expr = replaceall(expr, "1!=1", "0");
  expr = replaceall(expr, "1!=0", "1");
  expr = replaceall(expr, "0!=1", "1");
  expr = replaceall(expr, "0!=0", "0");

  return expr;
}

std::string simplify_bool_expr(std::string expr) {
  std::string answer = simplify(expr);
  return answer == "1" ? "true" : "false";
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  if (argc == 1) {
    std::cout << "Enter a boolean expression: ";
    std::string s;
    std::getline(std::cin, s);
    std::cout << simplify_bool_expr(s) << '\n';
  } else if (argc >= 2) {
    std::cout << simplify_bool_expr(argv[1]) << '\n';
  }
}
```

One thing I've noticed is that I make a lot of calls to `replaceall()`. Any suggestions on how to make this code faster?

Examples I've tried on my code successfully:

```
(true && false) || !false -> true
((false && true || false && false) || true && false) -> false
(true && (false || !false) || (false == true) && true) -> true
!((false && false) != ((true || (false && !false)) == true)) -> false
```

Some things I'd like to clarify:

- All of these boolean expressions are going to have exclusively constant values (true / false).
- I assume all input is valid.

Comment: Could you add a couple of example expressions you have successfully tested your code on?

Comment: Hey, just done that!

Comment: Your code happily accepts malformed input. In fact, it evaluates `1!!==1` to `true`.

Comment: @vnp yes, there's no error checking. I assume all input is valid, just edited that in.

Comment: You don't simplify, you evaluate. The former is more complicated, and can retain variables still to be defined.

Comment: @Deduplicator just edited that in too

Answer (score 1):

There are some small forgivable C++ beginner's short-comings.

Conceptually you want to replace *reducible expressions* (**redex**), especially operations with constants.

You chose to do that with strings and as simplification replaced `true` and `false` with respectively 1 and 0. That will not do with variable names like `x1`.
But would work for one-letter variables.

Nice would have been *regular expressions*, for C++ variables and for not nested `(...)`.

Alternative one can also use stacks and positions with length for tokens.

What would be nice to reduce the higher priority operations first, and then the lower priorities. And do for one operator the calculation:

```
X && 1     --> X
1 && X     --> X
X && 0     --> 0
0 && X     --> 0

! ! X      --> X
! 0        --> 1
```

Etcetera. Your reductions are far from complete. And there are some interesting laws.

Comment: Hey! I've edited my original post for the '!!'. Totally forgot about that! (since it's never used in production code). Some questions: what exactly are regular expressions? Why is the approach with stacks better than this?

Comment: Regex uses pattern matching. A variable could be `([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*)` which could be replaced as `... $1...`. Your code will be limited: `9+1==10` becoming `9+10`. However though the code shows a lack of knowing string functions, the concept of _reducible expressions_ is a wonderful tool.

Comment: Why the two mentions of C in this answer, when this is a C++ review?

Comment: @TobySpeight admittedly this review was not thorough with some leeway. Done with my smart phone. Because of the really long lists of replace cases, I wanted to introduce redexes, operator based matching, maybe even a stack of parentheses. For the rest I find the OP's solution refreshing, though a bit incomplete due to a missing system.

Comment: So that's just a typo? I'll make an edit for that.

Answer (score 1):

### Missing header

```
#include <string>
```

### Misspelt type name

`size_t` is in the `std` namespace, so write it `std::size_t` (it seems that your platform also defines it in the global namespace - you can't portably rely on that).

### Don't pass strings by value unless you need a copy

Pass as reference to const, or (better) as a string *view*.

### Use the library

`find_in_string()` is just a reimplementation of `std::string::find()`.  Prefer to use the standard library function - it has been honed by finer minds than yours or mine to do the job well.

There's not a standard library `replace_all()`, but we can still improve the implementation:

- first, reserve capacity for the new string (we can calculate this from the lengths of the argument strings and the number of non-overlapping matches).
- Build the new string from chunks of `std::string_view` rather than one character at a time.

### Type mismatch

We have functions that return a `std::size_t`, which is unsigned, but then write `return -1;` without a cast.  That should be a compiler warning (if not, you haven't enabled sufficient warnings for my liking).

It seems that we don't properly handle this return value - e.g. this fragment is totally broken when `get_matching_brace` returns such a large value:

> ```
> size_t end = get_matching_brace(expr, begin);
>
> expr = expr.substr(0, begin) +
>        simplify(expr.substr(begin + 1, end - begin - 1)) +
>        expr.substr(end + 1, expr.length());
> ```

Comment: I didn't use `std::string::find()` because I can't figure out how to pass in a specific start and end range to search. The `return -1` is intentional; and is equivalent to `std::string::npos`, it will automatically get converted to that. Also, in my original question, I mention that I assume all input is valid, including parentheses, which is why I don't add error handling in the last part.

Comment: Oh yes, you did mention that assumption.  I tend to always assume that input is evil, and write robust code.  I encourage you to do the same!

Comment: `return -1;` should still cause a warning - if you have that one disabled, you'll overlook other type mismatch errors.  I recommend `static constexpr not_found = static_cast<std::size_t>(-1);` if you want to indicate errors that way (but you've said that input is always valid, so obviously that return value isn't needed?!)

Comment: `find()` accepts a start position argument, and it's easy to test whether the result is higher than you want.  Or you could `std::string_view::find()` with substring within which you want to search.  String views are great for processing substrings of larger strings.

Comment: How can you pass in a start range to `find()`? Suppose I have an `std::string s = "foo me bar me hello world";` and I wanted to look for `"me"` after index `8`, but before index `13`. How would that look in code?